# How to search a list for all the words with two of a certain letter in it?

Tags: r

Using Rstudio, how can I find all the words that have two of a certain letter in them using grep/grepl and sub/gsub?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to find states with two or more `"a"`s in them you could use :

```
grep('.*a.*a.*', state.name, value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)

# [1] "Alabama"        "Alaska"         "Arizona"        "Arkansas"      
# [5] "California"     "Delaware"       "Hawaii"         "Indiana"       
# [9] "Kansas"         "Louisiana"      "Maryland"       "Massachusetts" 
#[13] "Montana"        "Nebraska"       "Nevada"         "North Carolina"
#[17] "North Dakota"   "Oklahoma"       "Pennsylvania"   "South Carolina"
#[21] "South Dakota"
```

If you want exactly two `"a"`s, we can use `str_count` to count number of `"a"`s and then subset.

```
state.name[stringr::str_count(state.name, 'a|A') == 2]

# [1] "Arizona"        "California"     "Delaware"       "Hawaii"        
# [5] "Indiana"        "Kansas"         "Louisiana"      "Maryland"      
# [9] "Massachusetts"  "Montana"        "Nebraska"       "Nevada"        
#[13] "North Carolina" "North Dakota"   "Oklahoma"       "Pennsylvania"  
#[17] "South Carolina" "South Dakota"
```

Answer (score 2):

To find exactly 2 `"a"`s using only base R you could do:

```
state.name[nchar(state.name) - nchar(gsub('[Aa]', '', state.name)) == 2]
#  [1] "Arizona"        "California"     "Delaware"       "Hawaii"        
#  [5] "Indiana"        "Kansas"         "Louisiana"      "Maryland"      
#  [9] "Massachusetts"  "Montana"        "Nebraska"       "Nevada"        
# [13] "North Carolina" "North Dakota"   "Oklahoma"       "Pennsylvania"  
# [17] "South Carolina" "South Dakota"
```

Comment: same idea `state.name[nchar(gsub('[^Aa]', '', state.name)) == 2]`

Comment: @rawr nice, that's definitely more elegant